# How to handle functionality (in a good approach/Better way) , if Push Notification not delivered to My device.?

Tags: android, ios, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-messaging

While reading some article about push notifications, I got to know that `push notifications` will not be delivered 100% to the device.

In this case how can handle my application functionality in a better way ,
why I am asking is because in the `push notification`. I will be sending the last updated record id based on that I will be updating data /information  in my device.

If I am not receiving any push notification then I have to manage this situation based on some time slot I have to keep on checking the server to fetch the record if i am doing in this way then it will  affect for battery because keep on checking method whether some data as update or not

Which we will be the good way to handle this situation, I need a logic for better way of doing.

Comment: You should not send any vital data through push notifications since they might be unable to reach the client. If you really need to send something important from server to client you should use WebSockets.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - On contrary to documentation, Push Notification is working consistently for us.

Secondly, the way I would design this by keeping track of receipt of push notification. For instance:

1. Server Sent the Push payload to APNS and note down the time.
2. Client received the Push Notification and make a server call & inform the receipt of notification and pulls the record details.
3. If server did not receive a notification of push receipt within X period then trigger another push notification. OR
4. For any further service call, Server can also inform client of missed notification confirmation. Based on this client can trigger the server pull for that record. So, its not a timer based pull but a more informative decision based on data.

PS: From your description I believe you are sending push payload not exceeding 256 bytes.